# If every prime ideal of $A$ is maximal, then the chain ${}\dots \leq x^2 A \leq x A$ stabilizes, for all $x \in A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I was given this question, where $A$ is a commutative ring:

> If every prime ideal of $A$ is maximal, then the chain ${}\dots \leq x^2 A \leq x A$ stabilizes, for all $x \in A$.

Also, the clue:

> Consider $S_x = \{ x^n(1-xy) : n \in \mathbb{N} ,\, y \in A \}$. If $\, 0\notin S_x$, then get a maximal ideal $P$ with the property $P \cap S_x = \varnothing$.

I was considering the fact that, if $x$ is nilpotent, then the chain stabilizes trivially. Therefore, we can assume otherwise, and get a prime ideal $P$ such that $x \notin P$, and therefore it is maximal by hypothesis.

However, I am unable to derive anything else from this. I have thought about taking the quotient of the chain by $P$, but I haven't been able to conclude.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the hint? First of all, observe that what you have to prove is equivalent to proving that $0\in S_x$.

Comment: I have considered it, but I still can't see where the contradiction appears when $0 \notin S_x$.

Comment: Well, did you show there exists such a maximal ideal $m$, like the hint says? If so, it follows that the coset of $x^n(1-xy)$ is never zero in $A/m$. So now the problem that we want to solve in $A$ is reduced to the same problem in $A/m$. But $A/m$ is a field, so it's not hard to get a contradiction.