# Proving that if every prime ideal is maximal, then the sequence $...\leq x^2 A \leq x A$ stabilizes for all $a\in A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm having some trouble proving the following:

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring such that every prime ideal maximal. Prove that for all $x \in A$, the chain $...\leq x^3 A\leq x^2 A\leq x A$ stabilizes.

My teacher provided the following hint: Consider the set $S_x = { x^n(1-xy):n\in \mathbb N, y \in A }$. If $0\not \in S_x$ then $S_x$ is multiplicatively closed. Then get maximal ideal such that $P\cap S_x = \emptyset$

I started by proving that $0\in S_x \iff $ the sequence stabilizes.

Then, I assumed that $0\not\in S_x$ and found a maximal ideal $P$ such that $P\cap S_x = \emptyset$ and I also noticed that this implies that $P = A\setminus S_x$

But from here I don't see how I can get a contradiction.

How can this be done using the hint provided by the teacher?

Comment: You [and your classmates](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4834512/29335) should definitely talk to your teacher in a case like this. It was an assignment?

Comment: Not really. It's a set of exercises the teacher gave us to prepare for the upcoming exam. I didn't notice that Martim already made the same question 1 day earlier haha @rschwieb

Comment: You should use the search feature haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can define the same kind of set $S_{x+P}$ is the quotient $A/P$. Since $S_x\cap P=\emptyset$, the coset $x^n(1-xy)+P$ is never equal to $P$, which is equivalent to saying that the zero element of $A/P$ doesn't belong to $S_{x+P}$. So just as you showed for $A$, this means that the sequence

$...\leq (x+P)^3(A/P)\leq (x+P)^2(A/P)\leq (x+P)(A/P)$

of ideals in $A/P$ doesn't stabilize. But this is clearly a contradiction, because $A/P$ is a field.

The purpose of the hint was to reduce the original problem to the same problem in $A/P$. But in a field this problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I initially went with Mark's answer but eventually found another way of doing this. I'll post it here in case someone in the future stumbles upon this same question:

Given what I said in the post above, we have a maximal ideal $P$ such that $P\cap S_x = \emptyset$. We can take advantage of the following property of maximal ideals:

> If $M$ is a maximal ideal of a commutative ring $A$, then for all $x\in A$, either $x\in M$ or $1-xy\in M$ for some $y \in A$.

Now, if $x\in P$, then $x^n(1-xy)\in P$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$ and $y\in A$ and this is impossible because $P\cap S_x = \emptyset$.
Then $x\not\in P$, meaning that there exists $y\in A$ such that $1-xy\in P$, but this also implies that for any $n\in \mathbb N$, $x^n(1-xy)\in P$ which is also a contradiction.

Thus we conclude that $0\not \in S_x$ and thus the sequence stabilizes.

Comment: yes, you are right. I'll correct it @rschwieb